# investigate or compare the data being pushed and pulled in Azure Offline data Sync

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have following Azure mobile Client

```
public AzureCloudService()
{
    Client = new MobileServiceClient(AzureUrl, new CustomAzureClientMessageHandler());

}
```

And i attached following message handler to that client

```
   public class CustomAzureClientMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Do any pre-request requirements here
            request.Headers.Add("UserId", Settings.UserId);

            // Request happens here
            var response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            // Do any post-request requirements here
            return response;
        }
    }
```

And i sync local data with server with the help of following lines.

```
  // Push the Operations Queue to the mobile backed
            await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

 // Pull each sync table
            var table = await GetTableAsync<T>();
            await table.PullAsync();
```

Problem is I need to investigate/compare the data being pushed and pulled in Synchronization.

1) Is there any way to see what data being pushed and pulled in a Synchronization call? May be using the message handler I mentioned above?

2) or is there is any way to the do same in Table Controller  instead on mobile client?

It is really hard to debug thing when there are issues in sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to achieve this.I have got it from following sample.Thanks to the Author

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/Helpers/LoggingHandler.cs#L12

Solution is

1. Extend the SQLLite Store to enable Logging
2. Use the message handler for logging

**Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Extended SQlite Store which can log operations happen in the SQLite database
/// </summary>
public class MobileServiceSQLiteStoreWithLogging : MobileServiceSQLiteStore
{
    private bool logResults;
    private bool logParameters;

    public MobileServiceSQLiteStoreWithLogging(string fileName, bool logResults = false, bool logParameters = false)
        : base(fileName)
    {
        this.logResults = logResults;
        this.logParameters = logParameters;
    }

    protected override IList<JObject> ExecuteQueryInternal(string tableName, string sql,
        IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(sql);

        if (logParameters)
            PrintDictionary(parameters);

        var result = base.ExecuteQueryInternal(tableName, sql, parameters);

        if (logResults && result != null)
        {
            foreach (var token in result)
                Debug.WriteLine(token);
        }

        return result;
    }


    protected override void ExecuteNonQueryInternal(string sql, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(sql);

        if (logParameters)
            PrintDictionary(parameters);

        base.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(sql, parameters);
    }


    private void PrintDictionary(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            return;

        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            Debug.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Message Handler which enable to pass the customer headers as well as logging the Request, Response etc happen via the Azure Mobile client
/// </summary>
public class CustomAzureClientMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private bool logRequestResponseBody;

    public CustomAzureClientMessageHandler(bool logRequestResponseBody = false)
    {
        this.logRequestResponseBody = logRequestResponseBody;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Request is being sent: {0} {1}", request.Method, request.RequestUri.ToString());

        if (logRequestResponseBody && request.Content != null)
        {
            var requestContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(requestContent);
        }


        Debug.WriteLine("HEADERS in the request");

        foreach (var header in request.Headers)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", header.Key, string.Join(",", header.Value)));
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        Debug.WriteLine("Response from server: {0}", response.StatusCode);

        if (logRequestResponseBody)
        {
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(responseContent);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/04/07/deep-dive-on-the-offline-support-in-the-managed-client-sdk/

> There are scenarios where you want to catch and deal with the synchronization conflicts in the client. You can control all the synchronization operations by implementing the IMobileServiceSyncHandler interface and passing it when initializing the context. For example, this is an implementation of a sync handler which traces all the operations which are happening.

```
classMySyncHandler : IMobileServiceSyncHandler
{
    MainPage page;

    public MySyncHandler(MainPage page)
    {
        this.page = page;
    }

    publicTask<JObject> ExecuteTableOperationAsync(IMobileServiceTableOperation operation)
    {
        page.AddToDebug("Executing operation '{0}' for table '{1}'", operation.Kind, operation.Table.Name);
        return operation.ExecuteAsync();
    }

    publicTask OnPushCompleteAsync(MobileServicePushCompletionResult result)
    {
        page.AddToDebug("Push result: {0}", result.Status);
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            page.AddToDebug("  Push error: {0}", error.Status);
        }

        returnTask.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

> And we can use this synchronization handler by passing it to the overload of InitializeAsync in the sync context, as shown below:

```
var store = newMobileServiceSQLiteStore(StoreFileName);
store.DefineTable<TodoItem>();
AddToDebug("Defined table in the store");

var syncHandler = newMySyncHandler(this);
await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, syncHandler);
AddToDebug("Initialized the sync context");
```

Comment: .Thank you but i can see this is useful for online scenarios but not useful for syncing  offline tables with server when the app is backed to online.Specially when i wanted to investigate both Push and Pull .However i found an answer which i wil update here in the answer

Comment: My solution is for offline scenarios, as is the whole article I linked to. But I am glad you found a way to achieve what you required.